# Obtener un objeto dentro del ngOnInit

Tags: angular

Como puedo obtener un objeto que estoy recibiendo dentro del ngOnInit y llevarlo fuera de la clase dentro del mismo componente, me explico: estoy usando tabla de Angular Material [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/beggoegpvmk?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.html) y la idea es reemplazar los datos staticos por los que recibo de firebase.

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
  this.products = products;
 })
 }
```

La idea es pasar el objeto fuera de la clase:

```
const products = [

]

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = products;
```

Dejo una imagen donde esta todo el codigo para su entendimiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Imagino que la data obtenida es en forma de Promise y estás intentando asignar el valor que está dentro del cuerpo de una Promise hacia una variable que está fuera de una Promise, no es así?

Answer (score 0):

Tu código se ejecuta secuencialmente creando primero **products** y luego creando **ELEMENT_DATA** siendo una copia del contenido de **products**.

> Exacto una copia, si modificas **products** no le pasara nada a **ELEMENT_DATA** por ser variables distintas.  También tienes otro problema **ELEMENT_DATA** es una constante no podrás modificar su valor.

**No hay solución directa, lo que puedes intentar es..**

```
this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(prod => {
  this.ELEMENT_DATA = prod;
})
```

Para asignarle un valor a ELEMENT_DATA

> Claro pero qué **ELEMENT_DATA** no sea una constante